# PhpMyAdmin- Sharing data between two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to populate a field `id_owner` of table1 (video_games) with the `id` from table2 (owner).
Field `possessor` of table1 contains the same data as field `Name` of table2.
I'm working with PhpMyAdmin.

What i 've already tried that was found under StackOverflow :

```
UPDATE  t 
   SET t.`id_owner` = o.`id`
  FROM `video_games` AS t
         INNER JOIN 
       `owner` AS o 
         ON t.possessor = o.Name
```

Added quotes :

```
UPDATE  t 
   SET t.`id_owner` = o.`id`
  FROM `video_games` AS t
         INNER JOIN 
       `owner` AS o 
         ON t.`possessor` = o.`Name`


UPDATE `video_games` 
SET `id_owner` = `i`.`id`, 
FROM (
    SELECT `id` 
    FROM `owner`) `i`
WHERE 
    `i`.`Name` = `video_games`.`possessor`
```

without the aliases

```
UPDATE
    `video_games`,
    `owner`
SET
    `video_games`.`id_owner` = `owner`.`id`,

WHERE
    `video_games`.`possessor` = `owner`.`Name`;
```

Still get stuck with the same MySql error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE
>       `video_games`.`possessor` = `owner`.`Name``' at line 7

Comment: That first syntax looks like Microsoft SQL Server, rather than MySQL syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting Name in the inner SELECT. It should be like this:

```
UPDATE video_games 
SET id_owner = i.id
FROM (
  SELECT id, Name
  FROM owner) i
WHERE i.Name = video_games.possessor
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your idea but it resulted with the same error message.

Further research lead me to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html which proposition worked fine

```
UPDATE video_games,owner 
SET video_game.id_owner=owner.id
WHERE video_games.id_possessor=owner.id;
```